# What is 'Langlands quotient'?

Tags: representation-theory, langlands-program

Here is a proposition:

> Let $\pi$ be an irreducible unitary representation of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. It can be realized as a component of the induced representation from a character $(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ on the Borel group $B$. If $\pi$ is not square-integrable then it is a **Langlands quotient** $\chi_1 \boxplus \chi_2$. The central character is $\chi_1 \chi_2$.

My question is: What is the meaning of 'Langlands quotient ' here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Langlands quotient comes from the Langlands classification, and here is the unique irreducible quotient of the parabolically induced representation.